# Perl split csv line into variables

Tags: perl, csv, cgi-bin

I need split a csv line into variables

```
# sample data
"100-001","Bla Bla, Bla, Bla","","",0.00000,"W1",6.000,0.000
```

I tried this but the numerical fields does not have "" so it would not work...

```
($var0,$var1,$var2,$var3,$var4,$var5,$var6,$var7,$var8) = split(/\","/);
```

THANKS...

Comment: Have you looked into Text::CSV?

Comment: The string "would not work" is not a built-in error message in Perl.

Comment: use Text::CSV - it's all done for you.

Comment: The server where the script is hosted does not have Text:CSV is there another way?

Comment: Install Text::CSV yourself in your own directory, and add that directory using `BEGIN { push @INC, "/home/ptomblin/perl" }`

Comment: My main problem is that the text data has , inside the "" otherwise i would just split where the commas are now

Comment: Again, `Text::CSV` takes care of that for you.

Comment: Does the regex provided in my answer work for your data set?

Answer (score 4):

For CSV, you should use a parser. The obvious on is Text::CSV. If as you say, it is difficult to install modules, you can use the Pure Perl implementation, called [`Text::CSV_PP`](http://api.metacpan.org/source/MAKAMAKA/Text-CSV-1.21/lib/Text/CSV_PP.pm). Paste that into a file and use it. Problem solved.

The other way to attack this is to use the core module [`Text::ParseWords`](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aParseWords) which can do a decent CSV parse in a pinch.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::ParseWords;

print "$_\n" for parse_line( ',', 0, '"100-001","Bla Bla, Bla, Bla","","",0.00000,"W1",6.000,0.000');
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```pl
($var0,$var1,$var2,$var3,$var4,$var5,$var6,$var7,$var8) = 
    split(/(?<="|[0-9]),(?="|[0-9])/);
```

- `?<=` is a lookbehind assertion
- `?=` is a lookahead assertion

Comment: It **won't** work if you change the first data element to `"100-001,"` (instead of `"100-001"`), and won't work under many other c.s. To parse csv by regex is almost _rocket science_, Friedls [Regex Book](http://books.google.de/books?id=sshKXlr32-AC&lpg=PP1&hl=de&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false) dedicated at least [one chapter](http://books.google.de/books?id=sshKXlr32-AC&lpg=PP1&hl=de&pg=PA213#v=onepage&q&f=false) to it.

Comment: @rubberboots That's **correct**.  This would violate the rules of a csv field containing commas as the OP has provided.  We have to assume that his data set follows some kind of logic. OP does your data have unmatched quotes?

Comment: for the provided input, your regex would, of course, work. Another border case would be _whitespace_ around commas `..." , "...` or `csvtext , csvtext`

Comment: @rubberboots - you're right again, this would have to be customized to his dataset.  If it doesn't have much consistency, then writing a regex to fit all scenarios could be quite a challenge.

Comment: I upvoted your post very early on because I guessed (correctly) that you'll probably catch many downvotes later on. The problem here is that your *answer* should be able to instruct a newbie on the topic. But if there are many glitches that you still didn't correct (or at least explain) after being told ...

Comment: @rubberboots I guess I'm new to this, maybe I had some misconceptions about how this whole SO thing was supposed to work.  Are we expected to read the OP's mind?  I was under the assumption that this site encouraged at least some effort on the part of the original posters.  Otherwise this site is going to read: `Hey, I need code that does this....thanks`.  The snippet I posted works 100% for the dataset provided.  So... Moral of the story is `Post an answer that points the OP in the right direction without exploring every possible scenario not covered in the OP = -1`.  I guess I udnerstand now

Comment: I think **SO** is just another multi-user computer game environment as many others are. It's just a modern *text adventure*. Use it for your personal enlightment and try to learn something important from it by playing it hard ;-)